# Conditionally set X-Frame-Option

Tags: apache, ibmhttpserver

I am trying to set X-Frame-Options using IBM HTTP Server (IHS) 8.5.5.12 that is based on apache HTTP Server 2.2.32.

I have tried with SetEnvIf but don't have idea about how to compare environment variable in httpd.conf file.

I have tried same in IHS 9 with If condition and it works, but don't have idea about how to implement same in IHS 8.5.5.12

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{HTTP:X-Requested-From} == 'mobileapp'">
        Header unset X-Frame-Options
    </If>
    <Else>
        Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    </Else>
</IfModule>
```

Above code works fine in IHS 9, Can some one help here?

Regards
Mohammad Ashfaq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is that the `Header` directive can be conditional in Apache 2.2 but only on an environment variable. But `SetEnvIf` runs first and can set an environment variable based on a request header:

```
SetEnvIf X-Requested-From mobileapp is_mobile=1
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header unset X-Frame-Options env=is_mobile


$ wget -qS  http://localhost 2>&1 |grep X-F   X-Frame-Options:
SAMEORIGIN 
$ wget -qS  --header="X-Requested-From: mobileapp"
http://localhost 2>&1 |grep X-F 
$
```